# How to parallelize function that keeps track of previous values?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to parallelize the following python script.

```
import random

tmp = []
cur = 100

while len(tmp) < 1000:
    condition = random.choice([True, False])
    if condition:
        amt = cur * 0.1
        tmp.append(amt)
        cur = cur - amt
    else:
        cur = cur + 5

print(sum(tmp))
```

I get it that I can first parallelize an array of size 1000 and use `map` to get the value of `condition`, for example:

```
import random
x = range(1001)
rdd = sc.parallelize(x).map(lambda _:random.choice([True, False]))
print rdd.collect()
```

However, I am stuck at the reduce logic.

Comment: The problem is that the next `cur` depends on the previous one. So you cannot "automatically" parallelize the `reduce` logic (sometimes it is even simply impossible).

Comment: You want to simulate a stochastic process / Brownian motion I think. I do not think you can parallelize that as the value at moment _n_ + 1   depends on the previous value on moment _n_.